# CSS: Unique styling of a table

Tags: css

I have multiple tables on my website.

They are each styled by the following CSS:

```
#content table { border: 3px solid #FFF; }
#content table tr th { color: #FFF; background-color: #2a2d32; font-size:12px;}
#content table tr td, #content table tr th { border: 1px solid #FFF; padding: 5px; text-align: center; line-height: 1.4em; font-size:12px;}
```

However I wish to single out a particular table for unique styling
The table in question is here:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" >
<tr style="background-color:#ebe7e5;">
<td>Income </td>
<td>€ </td>
<td>€ </td>
</tr>
<tr class="PL">
<td>Sales</td>
<td><?php echo $cBalance; ?>3,549</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<th><strong>Total Income</strong></th>
<th></td>
<th><?php echo $pProductionCapacity; ?>3,705</th>
</tr>

<tr style="background-color:#ebe7e5;">
<td>Expenses </td>
<td>€ </td>
<td>€ </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I have tried putting an id on this table and then trying CSS, however it seems the 
main CSS (as shown above) still overrides my changes. Can someone please help?

For example I have added:

```
<table id="unique" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" >
```

With CSS as follows:

```
#unique td th {background-color: red;}
```

But it's not working.

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

### Ok so I have tried changing to:

```
#unique td {background-color: red;}
#unique th {background-color: red;}
```

However the th is not changing red, it is still the grey colour from the intial CSS:

```
#content table { border: 3px solid #FFF; }
#content table tr th { color: #FFF; background-color: #2a2d32; font-size:12px;}
#content table tr td, #content table tr th { border: 1px solid #FFF; padding: 5px; text-align: center; line-height: 1.4em; font-size:12px;}
```

Comment: did you try table #unique td th {background-color: red;}

Comment: Can you put all your CSS code?

Comment: Why? The problem has been solved below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`#unique td th` means: "every th inside a td inside #unique". If you mean "every td and also every th inside #unique", what you need is `#unique td, #unique th`

Comment: It can be... if you have nested tables.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have been so specific with your selectors for all the tables you may have to be even more specific for your unique table like this:

```
#content table#unique tr td, #content table#unique tr th { ... }
```

Really the `table` in your selector is redundant as a `tr`, `td` and `th` are always in a table. You could make your selectors simpler by doing:

```
#content th, #content td { ... }
```

and then your unique table would be:

```
#content #unique th, #content #unique td { ... }
```

### Edit

Here's a jsfiddle of what I mean http://jsfiddle.net/BNV22/

You either need to lose the unnecessary `table tr` from your selectors or you need to keep the selectors the same but add `table#unique` to the rules that you want to apply to your unique table.

Comment: In your edit you haven't done what I suggested you do. That's why it still doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you that has fixed everything, if I could give two accepted answers I would!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `#content table#unique` , and you have to put this code after the `#content table`  rule

or you could simple omit the `#content` for your normal tables